# Is there a way to run the repair and rebuild from the command line?

Tags: sugarcrm

I'm getting an "HTTP: 500 Internal Server Error" when trying to log in in my local environment that I just can't seem to figure out. It popped up after I ran the repair, probably because I broke something. I've undone every change I made. Unfortunately since the 500 error doesn't let me continue to the admin menu to actually do the repair I'm kind of stuck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a PHP script for that (I'll link it further below), however:

Did you try deleting `cache/*` yet?
This may solve your problem without the need of a CLI repair.

The files in the cache will usually be regenerated automatically when you revisit the site (unless the problem is somewhere else to begin with).

---

The Repair script: https://gist.github.com/bickart/5468138

Copy it into the sugarcrm directory and execute it there (as the same user that is used to run the webserver process! Otherwise you may have to fix file permissions/ownerships after).

*(I'd copy the script's contents there, but because of the copyright notice and missing license info - I rather not...)*

You may find different versions of the repair script in the same user's space or elsewhere on the internet.

---

If cache-delete + repair doesn't help, then delete all `*.ext.php` files in `custom/modules/` and `custom/application/` (but **not** those in `custom/Extension/`!)

Those files are automatically generated files that contain combined (concatenated) versions of your instance's Hook/Language/etc. extension files.

If you e.g. had a syntax error in your extension files at some point, it may stay in those `*.ext.php` files until you delete them and force regeneration.

(E.g. in cases where the defective file is removed rather than modified.
In such situations there's no extension file with a "newer" modification date to tell Sugar that the respective `*.ext.php` file is outdated and needs to be regenerated).

On GNU/Linux you can delete those files using `find custom/modules/ custom/application/ -name '*.ext.php' -print -delete`

---

When you get `500` server errors, make sure to check for errors in your sugarcrm.log and PHP log.

If a `.ext.php`-File is the problem, you should see its path in the PHP error log. You may choose to fix things manually in there.